# What is the default username and password in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I installed Netbeans and tryed to access the server's manager using: (id/pass)manager/manager, admin/admin, system/password... None of them worked.

Comment: They are configured in some Tomcat config file. As far as I remember, it was not very hard to find.

Comment: NetBeans IDE uses a separate set of configuration files and not the <TOMCAT_HOME>/conf directory, please refer my answer below for the  solution

Comment: NetBeans creates credentials in the Catalina Base (see http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2012/07/about-user-login-password-of-netbeans.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set Tomcat Manager Application User Name and Password for NetBeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321933/how-do-i-set-tomcat-manager-application-user-name-and-password-for-netbeans)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

My answer is tested on *Windows 7* with installation of *NetBeans IDE 6.9.1* which has bundled Tomcat version 6.0.26.  The instruction may work with other tomcat versions according to my opinion.

If you are starting the *Apache Tomcat* server from the Servers panel in NetBeans IDE then you shall know that the Catalina base and config files used by NetBeans IDE to start the Tomcat server are kept at a different location.

Steps to know the catalina base directory for your installation:

1. Right click on the *Apache Tomcat* node in Servers panel and choose properties option in the context menu.  This will open a dialog box named Servers.
2. Check the directory name of the field *Catalina Base*, this is that directory where the current `conf/tomcat-users.xml` is located and which you want to open and read. 
   (In my case it is `C:\Users\Tushar Joshi\.netbeans\6.9\apache-tomcat-6.0.26_base` )
3. Open this directory in `My Computer` and go to the conf directory where you will find the actual `tomcat-users.xml` file used by NetBeans IDE.  NetBeans IDE comes configured with one default password with `username="ide"` and some random password, you may change this username and password if you want or use it for your login also
4. This dialog box also have username and password field which are populated with these default username and password and *NetBeans IDE* also offers you to open the manager application by right clicking on the manager node under the *Apache Tomcat* node in Servers panel
5. The only problem with the *NetBeans IDE* is it tries to open the URL `http://localhost:8084/manager/` which shall be `http://localhost:8084/manager/html` now

Comment: Under Linux, this file is located at `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-<version_number>/conf/tomcat-users.xml`.

Comment: if you installed using apt, then its at /usr/share/tomcat9/etc/tomcat-users.xml

Answer (score 75):

Check the file in `<TOMCAT_HOME>/conf` named `tomcat-users.xml`.
If you don't find something there edit it to look something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="admin"/>
    <user username="admin" password="password" roles="standard,manager,admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 48):

In Tomcat 7 you have to add this to tomcat-users.xml (On windows 7 it is located by default installation here: c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\ )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

NOTE that there shouldn't be ANY spaces between roles for admin, as this list should be comma separated.

So, instead of this (as suggested in some answers:

```
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui, manager-script, manager-jmx, manager-status, admin-gui, admin-script"/>
```

it MUST be like this:

```
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helps.
One things I want to mention here that I face is first stop server then made any changes else when you stop server the server automatically discard the changes and our added credentials will not work. I face this issue, I know this sounds crazy but I did.

Comment: This works well even with tomcat 8 and 9.. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 24):

In Tomcat 7, 8, and 9 there is NO default user, so nobody can access a Manager app. You need to alter conf/tomcat-users.xml by adding new user with the role "manager-gui", like:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Look up here: https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-default-administrator-password/

Answer (score 20):

Go to "%TOMCAT_FOLDER%/conf/tomcat-users.xml" and configure the following :

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>
    <role rolename="admin"/>
    <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Hence, the username is "admin" and password is "admin"

Comment: This is the only answer here that worked for me. Careful though, you need to finish the roles attribute off with a double-quote. `<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager-gui,manager-script"/>`

Answer (score 9):

Open  `tomcat-users.xml` which should be in `C:\Tomcat 7.0\conf`

Add following lines in above file :

```
<tomcat-users>
     <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
     <user username="admin" password="" roles="manager-gui"/>

     <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
     <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="admin-gui"/>        
 </tomcat-users>
```

**Note :**

1. `admin-gui` -> Username & Password - Do not Change.
2. `manager-gui` -> you can change user name & password for this only. 
         [Here password is not given]

Answer (score 2):

In Tomcat 7, under `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat_users.xml`, see the `<user />` tag to see password.

Example:

```
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
```

Comment: Still got problems. tomcat_users.xml contains this: 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="manager"/>
 <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager"/>
</tomcat-users>

Maybe it interferes with win7... or with my antivirus nod.
I've tried all the solutions you mentioned.

Comment: Netbeans install it's own Tomcat. Make sure you configured the config (xml) that is found in the Netbeans side.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to look at the answers above, but you'll find that the manager app requires you to have a user with the role 'manager', I believe, so you'll probably want to add the following to your tomcat-users.xml file:

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="youruser" password="yourpass" roles="manager"/>
```

This might seem simplistic, but it's just a simple implementation that you can extend / replace with other authentication mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

in file /conf/tomcat-users.xml 
check or add:

```
......
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="ide" password="ide" roles="manager,tomcat,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 2):

Only this helped me:

To use the web administration gui you have to add the gui role :

```
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>

<user username="name" password="pwd" roles="admin,admin-gui,manager,manager-gui"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

First navigate to below location and open it in a text editor

```
<TOMCAT_HOME>/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```

For tomcat 7, Add the following xml code somewhere between `<tomcat-users>`

```
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="username" password="password" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Now restart the tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your `conf/tomcat-users.xml`. If there is nothing there, you'd have to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

Platform  NetBeans 7.3, Apache Tomcat 7.0.34 re: Tomcat Manager

I spent 3 days tracking this down because I thought I had a bad install.

**On Windows and Linux, NetBeans uses a separate file location for CATALINA_BASE:**

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqInstallationDefaultTomcatPassword

So you can modify the tomcat_user.xml under CATALINA_HOME: until your face turns blue, to no effect.

It appears that the IDE only requires, manager-script,admin roles under CATALINA_BASE:.

When I tried to add a user to the manager-gui role (to the correct tomcat_user.xml file), required for access to the Tomcat Manager, Tomcat stopped presenting the login dialog and went directly to the 401 access denied splash page.

It appears that the NetBeans package uses a locked-down version of TomCat.

I hope this saves everyone some time.

Answer (score 1):

**For Window 7, Netbeans 8.0.2 , Apache Tomcat 8.0.15**
C:\Users\JONATHAN\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\tomcat-users.xml
The Tomcat Manager Username and password is like below pic..
[image: tomcat-users.xml]

Answer (score 1):

Check the file in <TOMCAT_HOME>/conf named tomcat-users.xml.
If you don't find something there edit to look something like:

> You can access in tomcat Manager-App and Host-Manager. add two role in one line

```
  <role rolename="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="standard,manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If people still have problems after adding/modifying the tomcat-users.xml file and adding the relevant user/role for the version of Tomcat that they're using then please be sure that you've removed the comment tags that are surrounding this block.  They will look like this in the XML file:
`<!--`
`-->`
 
They will be above and below the user/role section.

Answer (score 0):

If your apache tomcat asking for password,then just follow these steps:
go to the home directory of apache
then go to webapps folder
 open the META-INF
inside that you will find an xml file named context.xml--open it in edit mode

and           ***REMOVE THE COMMENT FROM the   VALVE  tag***.

After that you dont need any user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

In conf/tomcat-users.xml you can see what's your actual user configuration, in my case is usually user="admin" and pass="1234"

Answer (score 0):

try tomcat tomcat as the default username and password (tomcat 7)