# Tomcat 7: still Cannot Log in Manager Application AFTER MODIFIED USERNAME & PW

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have the exact same question with this guy: [Tomcat 7 Manager - how to authenticate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042235/tomcat-7-manager-how-to-authenticate)

I'm using Windows and I downloaded the Tomcat 7.0.39 Installer for Windows. When the installer was running, I didn't set any username and password for it (which means I left these textfield blank). However, when I tried to look up the Server Status on the Tomcat server hompage, it reminded me to enter the username and password. Whatever I enter, included not entering anything, it wouldn't let me pass.

Then, I googled and modified the usernames and passwords as what I was told:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp936'?>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui, manager-script, manager-jmx, manager-status, admin-gui, admin-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Then, I restarted Tomcat. But I still cannot pass. I have searched very carefully but really cannot find an answer through Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been quite a long time since I asked this question. Sadly, I haven't got any answers. However, I happened to found a solution recently.

It turns out that it is the Tomcat 7.X's installer's fault. Tomcat 7.X's installer for windows, as I read somewhere on the Internet, has some problem/bugs itself, in another word, it is not as perfect as the zip file which can be used directly after decompressed. I tried the zip file and modified the **%TOMCAT FOLDER%/conf/tomcat-users.xml** file this time. Then I got the right result.

So, for those of you who is still using Windows, I suggest you **not using the Tomcat 7.X installer, but the cabinet file directly**.