# Tomcat 7 Manager can't login

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Trying to log in but can't.
My tomcat-users.xml, modified as I saw it here.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <tomcat-users>
      <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
      <role rolename="manager-script"/>
      <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
      <role rolename="manager-status"/>
      <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
      <role rolename="admin-script"/>
      <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui, manager-script, manager-jmx, manager-status, admin-gui, admin-script"/>
    </tomcat-users>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks fine ... maybe try adding a "tomcat" role ?? That is the only difference I see with my config

Comment: Have you stopped the Tomcat service since making these changes and re-started it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove the spaces between the roles for admin/admin. The list should just be comma separated as so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Didn't help in my case, I still get a 403.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue but for me the reason was the **server.xml** file.

Within the file there is a tag which **specifies the path of the tomcat-users.xml**:

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="/etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

You have to make sure the **pathname** is set correctly to the location of your **tomcat-users.xml** file.

Comment: Note that with Tomcat installed via homebrew this was the problem.

Comment: This answer helped me solve the problem with **TomEE** in the **docker**

Answer (score 7):

And also check if it is not commented with:

```
<!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 3):

You also need to restart Tomcat after making changes to `tomcat-users.xml` or `server.xml`, `context.xml` or `web.xml` for the changes to be effective.

In my case, the problem was I did not restart Tomcat after making changes. 
Also on Tomcat 7 I had assigned `manager-script`, `manager-gui` roles to the same user. So Tomcat gave 403 error to enforce CRSF protection.

**Wrong**:

```
<role rolename="manager-script" />
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<user username="maven-deployer" password="s3cret" roles="manager-script,manager-gui" />
```

**Correct**:

```
<role rolename="manager-script" />
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<user username="maven-deployer" password="s3cret" roles="manager-script" />
<user username="gui-manager" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissions and ownership on the file '/etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml'. It should owned by root and group ownership should be tomcat7.

-rw-r-----   1 root tomcat7   2101 Jan 22 10:34 tomcat-users.xml

This is on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, YMMV

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 tomcat7 installed from repo

What worked for me was removing the role definitions from the tomcat-users.xml file.  and then restarting tomcat.

my file now looks like this:

```
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
    -->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->
  <user username="admin" password="n0tmyr3alp455w0rd" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Notice the instructions tell you to define the user who belongs to manager-gui but it does not tell you to define the role "manager-gui"

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems with access **Tomcat**'s manager (v8.0) as part of **NetBeans** (v8.2) IDE under **Windows 10**.

The **actual** tomcat-users.xml file to add gui-manager user/password pairs is located at C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\ path. Open tomcat-users.xml file and add some rows:

```
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <user username="root" password="root" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
```

After that you should restart Tomcat and try access manager again.

Answer (score 0):

So if nothing else works for you check that here

I had messed in my server.xml with the following line

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="jdbc/myapp"/>
```

That here should always be `resourceName="UserDatabase"`

```
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
```

I mistakenly thought it had to do with my applilcation database and have configured it. This here is the tomcat user database not the database that you have to your application.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7-admin
```