# Cannot access Tomcat 7.0 with Ubuntu 14

Tags: tomcat

just installed Tomcat 7 with Ubuntu 14
(as a VMWare machine),but can't access manager; 
here are my conf files..first `server.xml`:

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
 define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
 Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
-->
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
-->
<!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.
AprLifecycleListener"        SSLEngine="on" />

<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
<!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.
JreMemory                            
LeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.
GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
<Listener   className="org.apache.catalina.core.
ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

<!-- Global JNDI resources
Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
-->
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
description="User database that can be updated and saved"
factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>

<!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
-->
<Service name="Catalina">


<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
-->


Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8081" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="8443" />
-->
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
-->

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />



<!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
-->
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" />

<!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
/docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
/docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
<!--
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
-->

<!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
via a brute-force attack -->
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
<!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
available for use by the Realm.  -->
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
</Realm>

<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">


<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.
AccessLogValve"    directory="logs"
prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

</Host>
</Engine>
</Service>
</Server>
```

and second, my `conf/tomcat-users.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
<user username="tom" password="" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: which user have you used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat 7 Manager - how to authenticate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042235/tomcat-7-manager-how-to-authenticate)

Answer (score 0):

There is a second UserDatabaseRealm defined in your server.xml:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" />
```

Delete that line and try again.

This on creates a new Realm without the reference to the JNDI resource defined above. The right reference is wrapped by the lockout realm defined below.