# what's username/password of tomcat basic authentication?

Tags: authentication, tomcat

I've digged the internet for the guide about how to set tomcat authentication,and yes,it really has a pop-up window,which allows me to input username/password,but it seems that my username/password is wrong.
I add fraction of my tomcat-user.xml here:

```
enter code here
<!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
```

and fraction of web.xml here:

```
enter code here
<auth-constraint>
  <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
  <role-name>both</role-name>
  <role-name>role1</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

All these "tomcat/tomcat,both/tomcat,role1/tomcat" don't work.
What's problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lujun

The file after update should look like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
<!--
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Restart tomcat and use admin/admin

Comment: aha,<!--xxx--> are examples,3q~~~

Answer (score 3):

depending on your tomcat version, this should work:

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager"/>
```

EDIT:
and please read this ;-)
[What is the default username and password in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829513/what-is-the-default-username-and-password-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the file "tomcat-users.xml"

File path `C:\Users\suman\Documents\Software\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\conf`

File Name `tomcat-users.xml`

```
<tomcat-users>
<!--
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```