# Why tomcat is not running in user account of window 7?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I have installed  netbean IDE8.0 and tomcat (by customize option in netbean during installation) in Administration account of window7. when i am running project in netbean it is ok . But when  i am running same project in same  netbean, in window user account, it is asking for tomcat user id and password, while i have not setted  any user id for tomcat. can any one help me, how to resolve this problem.        Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829513/what-is-the-default-username-and-password-in-tomcat might help

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `tomcat-users.xml` in the `conf` directory of your tomcat installation and edit the `username` and `password` accordingly. You can learn about UserDatabaseRealm in Tomcat 7 [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#UserDatabaseRealm)

Note : Netbeans might have set a credetials for tomcat during installation