# Tomcat Deployment error

Tags: tomcat

error while deployment in tomcat

```
  >C:\Users\SYSTEM7\Documents\NetBeansProjects\webbbbbbb\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1087: Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username and password with the "manager-script" role in the Tomcat customizer in the Server Manager.
    >See the server log for details.
    >BUILD FAILED (total time: 17 seconds)

    In build-impl.xml:1087 line has following xml Snippet:


    1086: <target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
    1087:  <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
    1086: </target>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321933/how-do-i-set-tomcat-manager-application-user-name-and-password-for-netbeans

Comment: thanks nobalG for design the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide full permission to administrator in (C:) or else change project workspace & Tomcat Server folder to another drive. This is good working... me and friend tried for a two days and found out.