# Wildfly: Management user vs Application user

Tags: wildfly

I downloaded Wildfly (**wildfly-13.0.0.Final**) and I want to configure it. I start `standalone.bat` in the bin folder of JBOSS_HOME directory (I use Windows platform).

I go to management console: `localhost:8080` -> Administration Console. I see this

> Your WildFly Application Server is running.
>   However you have not yet added any users to be able to access the admin console.
>
> To add a new user execute the add-user.bat script within the bin folder of your WildFly installation and enter the requested information.

I run `add-user.bat` and it asks me what kind of user I would like to add.
I need a user to have permissions to deploy, redeploy applications. For example, for Apache Tomcat I can consifure `tomcat-users.xml` file and add users there (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327730/4587961), so when I log into console as that user, I can deploy applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a Management user with the `add-user.bat`, whose credentials you will be able to log in the web admin with.

You could direclty add the user to the `mgmt-users.properties` file in the configuration directory of your standalone or domain, but the entry must be of the form `<username>:DIGEST-MD5(<username>:ManagementRealm:<password>)`, which the `add-user.bat` script will handle for you.

You don't need any particular role unless you set up RoleBasedAccessControl.

Applicative users are used by applications with frameworks such as JAAS and are interfaced through the "default" security-domain, which refers to the ApplicationRealm containing those users.

Answer (score 0):

As I read

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/240892

Management user is used to enter the web console. Here you can deploy app, make settings, add resources (JPA config for example). Application users do not have access to the web console. They can be used for example to authenticate services. For example to invoke remove EJB bean, you need application user credentials to access the remove server.